# VS solution folder not generating in the bin/debug or release folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have added a solution folder on my visual solution project.
I have added some text files inside that folder.

I have Built and Rebuilt my solution but still nothing.

The error I get when trying to access a file from the folder:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file0 = new System.IO.StreamReader(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"newFolder\SampleText.txt"));
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'I:\Programming\Projects\SampleProject\SampleProject\SampleProject\bin\Release\newFolder\SampleText.txt'.

The path to the Release folder is valid, but newFolder is not inside.
I don't understand why it is not being generated, any help would be great.

Comment: your code snippet will not generate the folder for you.  You need to create it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Is there not a way to generate folders created that are part of the visual studio solution? Because I need the file to pre-exist

Comment: You must understand difference between `Release` and `Debug` folders. By default you might be working in the `Debug` mode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Click on your text file, change `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer` or `Copy always`. This will copy the file and any folder structure beneath it up to the project level and re-create it in the output folder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Edit, my folder was at solution level not project level. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The answers correct. You need to change "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always" or "Copy If Newer" BUT YOU NEED TO DO ONE MORE THING. You need to choose Build Action as "Content". By doing so the folders that contain the files are generated in debug folder automatically without hassle. The other Build Actions may also work I am not sure but not "Resource" one.

Answer (score 0):

If you set text file's property "Copy to Output Directory" to "Always" in solution then folder that contains this file will be created automatically

Answer (score -1):

If you create your folder at the project level as opposed to the solution level, you can then go to each file in that folder and view the Properties (right-click / Properties).  Here, can then set the "Copy to Output Directory" option to "Copy Always" or "Copy if newer", whichever one is appropriate for your purposes.